# Cron to find exec cp and redirect output with time / date per line?

Tags: find, io-redirection, cp, exec

I try to setup a `cron` task to run a set of basic shell commands.

I need to look to any files created on the last day, then copy to another folder and generate a log stating, line by line, the date and the time of the file copy operation.

The two shell commands run separately but need to create one and schedule via `cron`. When I try to increase the first command (`find`) `cron` does not execute the task and gives errors. If I run manually, it works.

```
find /dir/ -type f -mtime -1 -exec cp -v -a --parents "{}" /dir2/ \; >> /dir2/LogsCopiaDBs_$(date +%d-%m-%Y).txt
exec &> >(while read line; do echo "$(date +'%h %d %Hh%Mm%Ss') $line" >> /dir2/LogsCopiaDBs.txt; done;)
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Is there a reason the sequence of commands needs to be in the `cron` table? This would be easier to do in a readable way in a script which could then be invoked by `cron`.

Comment: I use crontab only to schedule the script execution with these two lines. These two lines are not within the cron. My crontab looks like this:

* 2 * * * /backup/scriptdb.sh

Comment: The cron log does not contain any errors.

Comment: You want this to run every minute during the 2AM hour of the day?

Comment: DopeGhoti, It is just an example to facilitate testing.

Answer (score 0):

The lines should be in a different order:

```
exec &> >(while read line; do echo "$(date +'%h %d %Hh%Mm%Ss') $line" >> /dir2/LogsCopiaDBs.txt; done;)
find /dir/ -type f -mtime -1 -exec cp -v -a --parents "{}" /dir2/ \; >> /dir2/LogsCopiaDBs_$(date +%d-%m-%Y).txt
```

The `exec` line will replace `STDOUT` with the command specified, and the `find` line will perform the copy actions and output to `STDOUT` which is replaced by your logging command.

I think that you want to achieve that you fill two logfiles at once. One with the output of the copy commands, another with the date prefixed. To do that you can use the `tee` command. Without the `tee` command the output of the `find/cp` command is redirected to another logfile and is not captured by the `exec` command. The `tee` command solves this:

```
exec &> >(while read line; do echo "$(date +'%h %d %Hh%Mm%Ss') $line" >> /tmp/LogsCopiaDBs.txt; done;)
find /tmp/ -type f -mtime -1 -exec echo cp -v -a --parents "{}" /tmp/ \; |tee -a /tmp/LogsCopiaDBs_$(date +%d-%m-%Y).txt
```

Comment: Sorry, I had not said I tried this mode (first exec then find) and works only when run manually if I schedule via Cron does not. The logs in cron proves that the script was executed but does not occur any copy or log generation.

Comment: Works only manually, via cron does not work and does not generate error.